# $a,r$ are integers and $q$ is a prime prove that there is a prime p satisfy $a^{q^r}\equiv 1 (\text{mod}\ p)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

> Let $a,r$ are integers and $q$ is a prime prove that there is a prime
> p satisfy $a^{q^r}\equiv 1 (\text{mod}\ p)$.

It is said that $p|(a^{q^r}-1)$ . I saw it in an algebraic number theory textbook , and it looked like an elementary number theory problem. I think it's obvious in a sense, but it doesn't seem that simple.

Comment: Won't any prime divisor of $a^{q^r}-1$ work for $p$?

Comment: Saying $x \equiv 1 \bmod p$ means $p \mid (x-1)$, i.e., $p$ is a factor $x-1$, *not* that $(x-1) \mid p$.  Watch out.

Comment: @KCd, yes, I went by what OP wrote and got confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That you saw something like what you wrote in an algebraic number theory book made me remember your notation appears in the following theorem in Lang's *Algebraic Number Theory*:

**Theorem**. *Let $a, r$ be integers $> 1$. Let $q$ be a prime number. Then there exists a prime number $p$ such that $a \bmod p$ has order $q^r$.*

See Lemma 1 on page 200 in the 1st edition (the start of Section 2: *Existence of a conductor for the Artin symbol*).

That $q$ is prime means that $a \bmod p$ has order $q^r$ exactly when  $a^{q^r} \equiv 1 \bmod p$ and $a^{q^{r-1}} \not\equiv 1 \bmod p$. (In the subject line you omitted that second condition.) In particular, $q^r \mid (p-1)$, so we have the lower bound $p > q^r$.

The idea in the proof is to look at prime factors of $(a^{q^r}-1)/(a^{q^{r-1}}-1)$, which is an integer. The argument takes about half a page, and it's not difficult, but just needs a bit of care.